# Status report for Commerce Kickstart 7.x-2.41 reads Not supported

Tags: 7, commerce

Just upgraded from commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.38 to commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.41. When I view the status report it shows "Unsupported release" for module and theme update status. When I click on the list, it shows the following message:

> Distro Update Manager: libraries version 7.x-2.2 does not match .make
>   file version 7.x-2.3 from commerce_kickstart.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. The best solution, but not necessarily the easiest, is to use drush. You can find the instructions at [Installing & upgrading Drupal Commerce](https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/install) under the "Updating your files" section.

**tl;dr**

Here’s the workflow. Be sure to backup your files and database first!

1. Move your */sites* folder, *.htaccess* and all non Drupal stuff out of your docroot
2. Delete your old *commerce_kickstart* installation. Your docroot folder should be empty.
3. Run `drush dl commerce_kickstart`. It will fetch and intall the latest commerce_kickstart version
4. Move back your */sites* folder, *.htaccess* from above
5. Run `drush updatedb -y`

Comment: Thanks leymannx but that is the workflow I followed.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem.  The .make file for commerce_kickstart. was changed to reference version  7.x-2.3 of the Libraries module.  This module is not included in core or in commerce kickstart, so the module is in my /sites directory.  I was still running version 7.x-2.2.  I upgraded to version 7.x-2.3 and the error went away.